# Android: How to: determine if a Location is between LocationA and LocationB in Android way?

Tags: android

How do you determine if LocationX is between LocationA and LocationB? Is there an Android way to determine it?

**UPDATE**
I am asking here if LocationX is on the BuildingA or on the BuildingB. I have the upper left and lower right coordinates of the two buildings.

**UPDATE2**
Let say LocationX is a person. Main goal is to determine if that person is on the BuildingA or is on the BuildingB.

**UPDATE3**
Let say that BuildingA and BuildingB are rectangle/square. so we just need upper left and lower right latitude and longitude.

**UPDATE4**
Let me to add code snippet from @ligi 's response. But the code below is failed.

```
Location locationA = new Location("A");
locationA.setLatitude(35.70217034224572);
locationA.setLongitude(139.74359443782043);
Location locationB = new Location("B");
locationB.setLatitude(35.69994863045598);
locationB.setLongitude(139.74633029101562);
Location locationX = new Location("X");
// TODO result: X:169.661 Y:347.359
locationX.setLatitude(35.70066307001967);
locationX.setLongitude(139.74450102446747);

//distanceAB > (distanceXA + distanceXB - threshold)
float threshold = 0f;
float distanceAB = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
float distanceXA = locationX.distanceTo(locationA);
float distanceXB = locationX.distanceTo(locationB);
boolean result = distanceAB > (distanceXA + distanceXB - threshold);
assertTrue(result);
```

Comment: what means `LocationX is between LocationA and LocationB` ?

Comment: Let me to use coordinates. Is coordinateX is between coordinateA and coordinateB. Is there other terminology? Don't have idea on how to explain it, aside from that. My apology.

Comment: It is a Location object from GPS.

Comment: Dunno about specific android method but you'll have the long and lat so use those. (IE latA > latX > latB && longA > longX > longB and check for A < B, etc )

Comment: AFAIK Coordinate has two values ... so ... 1. coordinateX can lays in "rectangle" made from coordinateA and B on sphere ... 2. coordinateX lays on line between CoordinateA and B

Comment: I have updated the post. Would you take a look. I am pretty sure that there is already well tested logic for that. I just can't find it. I am still searching.

Comment: i just thought about it ... and ... well ... if we take my 1st definition LocationX is **always** between LocationA and LocationB(on sphere)

Comment: Your update actually makes me _more_ confused. You have two buildings, located at A and B. Then you have a point X. What exactly is it you want to know? If X lies along the direct path between A and B (what your initial question seems to ask)? Or if X lies with a confined area surrounding either point A or B (which is what your update seems to be asking)?

Comment: My sincere apology, I have added UPDATE2.

Comment: Ok, well to me, this question has completely changed. Initially it was about determining if a point lies on a path between two other points. And ligi gave a [solid answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361643/android-how-to-determine-if-a-location-is-between-locationa-and-locationb-in-an/7362078#7362078) to that below. But now it appears you have two points, and want to determine if a location is close in proximity to one or the other. In that case, find the distance between A and X and see if it is less than a predetermined value. If not, check the same for A and Y.

Comment: I'm afraid not, it is totally the same. LocationA (upper left coordinate) and LocatioB (lower right coordinate) are the Location object from Android GPS of a building. LocationX is the person.

Answer (score 3):

calculate 3 distances ( e.g. via Location.distanceTo ) : distanceAB , distanceXA , distanceXB
then check the following: (distanceAB == (distanceXA + distanceXB)) 
and you might introduce a bit of fuzzynes with some threshold bigger than 0 as in the example check - depending on the use case - as in reality things will not be optimal strung

I see that the problem has changed with the updates - the new problem could be addressed e.g. with Rect.contains - just build a Rect for each building and check with Rect.contains if your person is in the building.

Comment: This will only work for a point that's exactly in the middle of AB. So if there's a point that's very close to A, but very far from B, yet still lies on the path between A and B, this point won't be considered. And the larger AB is, the more pronounced the effect will be.

Comment: Would you elaborate more these phrases-> (1) you might introduce a bit of fuzzynes with some threshold bigger than 0 (2) as in reality things will not be optimal strung

Comment: (distanceAB == (distanceXA + distanceXB)) only is true in theory but probably not with your praxis values - so you should better do (distanceAB > (distanceXA + distanceXB - threshold))

Comment: @ligi i tried your answer but it failed. would you refer to the above code snippet..

Answer (score 1):

A point (a,b) is contained in the rectangle defined by the two points (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) if minimum(x0,x1) < a < maximum(x0,x1) and minimum(y0,y1) < b < maximum(y0,y1).

A point (a,b) is on the line connecting (x0,y0) to (x1,y1) if  a - y0 = ((y1-y0)/(x1-x0))*(b - x0), assuming x1 != x0.  If x0 does equal x1, (a,b) is on the line if and only if a also equals x0.

The distance between the point (a,b) and the point (x0,y0) is the square root of (a-x0)^2+(b-y0)^2.

Comment: what do you mean by minimum and maximum? is it functions from Android?

Comment: I mean the smallest of the two numbers (minimum) and the largest of the two (maximum).  java.lang.Math gives you min and max functions (see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html)